# Outlet trips GFCI outlet

Tags: receptacle

Replaced 15v outlet with another basic one. All seemed to go well during install, but after it was over, the gfci outlet trips when I place a reasonable load to it.

When left alone, power flows though the outlet to the rest of the devices. When I plug a lamp in it, it's fine. When I plug my surge protector in it with only a modem and router on it, it trips. It was on the old outlet.

When it trips, it's only the gfci before it and everything before gfci works when tripped.

There are four main wires. Two white and two black. Then my green ground. I placed two live wires on top. On mine, it didn't really specify where so I left as old ones in the past. It did say the white and black side. I did separate and verify ground was on top to make sure.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense. Can you take a picture?

Comment: I'm also confused by your wiring description, though it makes me question if the wiring is correct. Another option is your surge protector is faulty, or there is a fault in the connected wiring (eg disconnected neutral), and the GFCI is correctly doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing. I'm not clear on if the new GFCI is replacing an old GFCI or a standard outlet, but what promted you to install the new GFCI specifically? Have you tried plugging anything else into the new GFCI and does it trip? A (labelled) picture or diagram of the wiring you did would help greatly.

Comment: Why did you replace the receptacle? Was the grounding conductor attached to the old receptacle? Some surge protectors work by directing the surge to the grounding conductor. With this type of surge protector,  it's possible a surge could cause a GFCI protecting the circuit to trip.